# Limit of Function series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Given that $$g(x):=\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ { (\cos(x)) }^{ 2n } } $$
>   Find 
>      $$h(x)=\lim _{ m\rightarrow \infty  }{ { g(x) }_{ m } } $$
>   Where
>   ${ g(x) }_{ m }:=g(2\pi m!x)$.

---

I already computed $g(x)=0$
but I can't compute $h(x)$ the same way I did with $g(x)$.
Could someone give me a hint on how to start computing $h(x)$?

Comment: Your calculation for $g(x)$ is wrong; can you explain why?

Comment: yes it is g(x)=1 since  lim ${cos(x)) }^{ 2n }$=L using ln on both sides (and some further calcs) gives ln($cos(x)) }^{ 2n }$=0 gives g(x)=1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} x^{2n}=
 \begin{cases} 
      \infty & |x| > 1 \\
      1 & |x| = 1 \\
      0 & |x| < 1 
   \end{cases}
$$
In your case, $\cos x\le1$ . Note that $\cos(2\pi m!x)$ is a rather convoluted notation for the simpler $\cos(2\pi zx)$ where $z$ is an integer.

Now what is the value of $\cos(2\pi zx)$ always equal to? Can you now solve the limit?

---

**Remark:**

> But what if $zx=1/4$, wouldn't $\cos(2\pi zx)=\cos (\pi/2)=0?$

That would not actually happen. Since $z=m!$, that implies that even if $x=p/q$ (in reduced form, $p,q\in Z$), that $q$ will get cancelled with $m!$, as $m!=1\cdot 2\cdot3...\cdot (q-1)\cdot q\cdot (q+1)....m$.

Because $m\to\infty$, we are covering all integers that could possibly ever exist (at least theoretically), hence we are sure to have $q$ get cancelled at some point, and the $2\pi$ would remain safe.

Comment: Please, could you write the answer using standard math notations? I mean... the "equality"  $$x^{2n}=\begin{cases}\infty&|x|>1\\ 1&|x|=1 \\ 0&|x|<1\end{cases}$$ is a little strange in my eyes. 

(Forgive me if my message seems to be rude, it's not my intention, English is not my mother tongue.)

Comment: @Ixion Sure. But that notation is a standard notation for [piece wise functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise#Notation_and_interpretation). Let me know if the info on the link doesn't help.

Comment: it's equal to 1 for all z because of 2k-periodic?

Comment: @MasterPI Yes, it is. Then, what does the value of the limit become?

Comment: Your answer fails to point out what happens when $x$ is rational.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thanks! I added the case. Please review

Comment: using what is stated above for x^(2n) the limit is either 1 or infinity?

Comment: @MasterPI Remember that it will be $\infty$ only when $\cos(...)>1$. But can $\cos(...)>1$? Then, what will your final answer for the limit be?

Comment: No it can't get >1, so the limit will always be equal to 1

Comment: @MasterPI Correct! :)

Comment: That is not standard notation. Please edit.

Comment: @zhw. Done. Though I'll honestly admit it looks less elegant now.

Comment: It should also have been acceptable if you had written $$\lim_{n\to\infty}x^{2n}=\begin{cases}\infty&|x|>1\\ 1&|x|=1 \\ 0&|x|<1\end{cases}$$ or : ... for $n\to\infty$, $$x^{2n}\to\dots.$$

Comment: No, using the display format is fine (and you should go back to it). Writing  $=$ when it is not an equality is not fine however. See the comment of @LutzL

Comment: @zhw. Ok, done. Please see.